# delete button is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am going to delete the particular row of my database, but when i delete the button it tells me that undefined display in deletebookajax.php on line no 54..
So can u please tell me where i have gone wrong...
here is my code
book.php is for displaying the entire book details....

```
<?php
include('assets/page_header.php');
include('db/db.php');
?>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style>
h1 {
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<h1>BOOKS PAGE</h1>



<?php
error_reporting(0);

$str="select * from books";

$query1=mysql_query($str);

$q=mysql_num_rows($query1);

//$query2=mysql_query("select status from bookrentalinfo where bookid=$bookid");
//echo $query2;
//$res=mysql_fetch_array($query2);
echo "<table align='center'>";
echo "<tr><th>BookID</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Publisher</th><th>Numcopies</th><th>Shelfno</th><th>Status</th><th colspan=2  >Action</th></tr>";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$rows['bookid']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['title']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['author']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['publisher']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['numcopies']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['shelfno']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['status']."</td>";
echo "<td><button class='button1' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete' id=".$rows['bookid']." value='delete' name='delete'><img id='image' src='./images/trash.png'/></button></td>";
echo "<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' href='edit1form.php?book_id=".$rows['bookid']."'><img id='image' src='./images/small.gif'/><span class='tooltiptext' >Edit</span></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
<div id="display">
</div>



<!--echo "<td><button type='button'>delete</button></td>";
/*if($res['status']=="BORROWED")
{
echo "Sorry You Can't Delete The Book";
}
else
{
echo "The Row Is Deleted";
}*/-->




<script type="text/javascript">

$('document').ready(function() {

    $(".button1").click(function(e) {

     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
 var strconfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
if(strconfirm)
{ 
    var bookid=$(this).attr("id");
    alert(bookid);





    dataString='book_id='+bookid;
    alert(dataString);



            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "db/deletebookajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            alert("submitted"+result);
            $('#display').html(result);
            window.location.href="books.php";
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }
            });



    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
        });

        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

deletebookajax.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['book_id']))
{
    $bookid = $_GET['book_id'];
    echo $bookid;
}
include('../assets/page_header.php');
?>


<input type="hidden" name="bookid"  value=<?php if(isset($bookid)) echo $bookid; ?>>





<?php
include('db.php');

//if(isset($_POST['bookid']))
//
//$bookid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bookid']);
$delete = "delete from books WHERE bookid=$bookid";

$query1=mysql_query($delete);
echo $query1;

if($query1)
{
$q=mysql_query("select * from books");
echo $q;
$display="<table>";
$display.="<tr><th>BookID</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Publisher</th><th>numcopies</th><th>shelfno</th><th>status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$display.="<tr>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['bookid']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['publisher']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['numcopies']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['shelfno']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
$display.= "</tr>";
}
$display.="</table>";

}


else
{
$display.= "U can't delete The book";
}
//echo "nothing";

echo $display;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using an unmaintained, insecure, and long-deprecated database API. Stop NOW. Alternatives like PDO have been available for more than ten years. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @miken32 In other words, it's "deprecated" and no longer supported.

Comment: ha ok sir,...can u detect my error sir, please

Comment: use `else { $display = "U Can't delete the book";}`

Comment: are sending the request to databse so maybe AJAX type is Post intesed of GET.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your deletebookajax.php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['book_id']))
{
    $bookid = $_GET['book_id'];
    echo $bookid;
}
include('../assets/page_header.php');
?>


<input type="hidden" name="bookid"  value=<?php if(isset($bookid)) echo $bookid; ?>>





<?php
//include('db.php');

//if(isset($_POST['bookid']))
//
//$bookid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bookid']);
$user="root"; 
$server="localhost"; 
$password=""; 
$db="library book"; 
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$db);

$delete = "delete from books WHERE bookid=$bookid";

$query1=mysqli_query($dbconn, $delete);
echo $query1;


if($query1)
{
$q=mysqli_query($dbconn, "select * from books");
echo $q;
$display="<table>";
$display.="<tr><th>BookID</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Publisher</th><th>numcopies</th><th>shelfno</th><th>status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($dbconn, $q))
{
$display.="<tr>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['bookid']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['publisher']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['numcopies']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['shelfno']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
$display.= "</tr>";
}
$display.="</table>";

}


else
{
$display = "U can't delete The book";
}
//echo "nothing";

echo $display;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok sir, but also the same error u cant delete the book  is displaying.

Comment: In your query part is this running correct: `$query1=mysql_query($delete);` ?, Because now use only PDO So `Mysqli_query();` is correct way to use.

Comment: yes sir, i copied the delete query and executed in sql yog, it is working fine.....

Comment: Add this after your `mysql_query($delete);` `if (mysql_error()) die('Error, insert query failed');`

Comment: So you use this query instead that `mysqli_query($con,"delete from books WHERE bookid=$bookid");`

Comment: eventhough i include $user="root";
$server="localhost";
$password="";
$db="library book";
$dbconn= mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($db,$dbconn);
i replaced the above code by removing include('db.php');

Comment: sir i m getting mysql expexts parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: again same error wherever it sees display ...it is telling display is undefined........

Comment: did you get your $bookid ?

Comment: sir i got the result....because i was deleting directly from book which referencing the bookid in bookrentalinfo..

Comment: therefore i deleted firdt bookid in bookrental and then i deleted it got deleted..